# error while installing NS2 in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10, ns2

this error after including deb

```
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe in sources.list
```

```
    Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
    Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
    Reading package lists... Done
```

please help

Comment: You added a bionic=18.04 source to 21.10 ... why? You don't need to add anything manually. Enabling `universe` repository is as easy as `sudo apt-add-repository universe`.

Answer (score 0):

> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
> is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

Conditions: A line `deb [url] bionic main universe` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Install the key ..... and g++-4.8

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

gpg --export --armor 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install g++-4.8
```

The ns2 build ( ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-EyPhoScBFDb7ul0VFk6FZQ )

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install
```

..... No issues, Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1                         this type of error showed

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean. Please add all new information to your question https://askubuntu.com/posts/1370767/edit ...... and never in a comment. ........ I did as my answer says : No issues at all.